# Generate random 256 hex value

Tags: postgresql

I need to generate a random 256 hex value for an insert statement. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

`... encode(digest(uuid_generate_v4(), 'sha256'), 'hex')`

Comment: What about it "doesn't work?" Error? Wrong output? Can you update your post with those details?

Answer (score 0):

It seems I needed to cast the `uuid_generate_v4()` to text.

`encode(digest(cast (uuid_generate_v4() as text), 'sha256'), 'hex')`

Comment: I thought it might also be missing extension's - CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pgcrypto;
select encode(digest(uuid_generate_v4():: text, 'sha256'), 'hex');